# Editar linhas em vbscript

Tags: vbscript

Estou tentando aprender VBS para resolver um problema que aconteceu quando tentei importar um arquivo no meu sistema. O arquivo possui mais de 4000 linhas e todas as linhas devem ter 240 caracteres. (Não tenho backup)

Atualmente, o documento está desconfigurado assim:

A primeira linha está ok, com 240.

A segunda linha está apenas com CRLF.(0).

```
240 + 0 = 240
```

A terceira linha está com 238 caracteres + CRLF (238 caracteres).

A quarta linha está com 2 caracteres + CRLF (2 caracteres).

```
238 + 2 = 240
```

A quinta linha está com 236 caracteres + CRLF (236 caracteres).

A sexta linha está com 4 caracteres + CRLF (4).

```
236 + 4 = 240
```

A sétima linha está com 234 caracteres + CRLF (234 caracteres).

A oitava linha está com 6 caracteres + CRLF (6 caracteres).

```
234 + 6 = 240
```

Notei que esse padrão continua por todo o arquivo, portanto creio que consigo corrigir isso por VBS.

Alguém poderia me auxiliar a criar um script para resolver esse problema?

Creio que devo ler cada linha, usar Len() para verificar a quantidade de caracteres e dar um DELETE onde seria o CRLF caso a linha tenha menos de 240 posições.

Ou talvez fazer Split e concatenar a linha k com a linha k+1, num loop onde k começa com 0(linha 1 do arquivo) e receberá K = K+2 a cada iteração.

Vou tentar primeiro fazer a opção do Split. Caso alguém queira colaborar com algum tipo de código ou apenas dizer uma forma mais inteligente de solucionar o caso, agradeço!

Answer (score 1):

Script vbs:

```
Dim arq
Dim obj

Set obj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set arq = obj.OpenTextFile(WScript.Arguments(0), 1)

Dim texto
Dim conteudo
Dim tamanho

texto = arq.ReadAll
arq.Close
Set obj = Nothing

conteudo = Split(texto, vbCrLf)
tamanho = UBound(conteudo) - LBound(conteudo) + 1

Dim i
Dim numlinha

numlinha = 0
Do While numlinha < tamanho
    Dim novo
    novo = conteudo(numlinha)

    If Len(novo) < 240 Then
        Dim primeiralinha
        primeiralinha = numlinha
        Do While numlinha < tamanho And Len(novo) < 240
            numlinha = numlinha + 1
            novo = novo & conteudo(numlinha)
        Loop
        If Len(novo) <> 240 Then
            Err.Raise vbObjectError + 514, _
                "Erro concatenando linhas entre " & (primeiralinha + 1) & _ 
                " e " & (numlinha + 1) & " (inclusive)"
        Else
            WScript.Echo novo
        End If
    ElseIf Len(novo) > 240 Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 515, _
            "Linha " & (numlinha + 1) & " tem mais de 240 caracteres"
    Else
        WScript.Echo novo
    End If

    numlinha = numlinha + 1
Loop
```

Para usar:

```
cscript script.vbs c:\dados\meuarquivo.txt > c:\dados\meunovoarquivo.txt
```